# WPF GridViewColumn align doesnt work

Tags: c#, wpf

I want the information in `GridViewColumn` "from" aligned to the right.

This is what I have done and its not working:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding VolumeNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
       <ListView.View>
          <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
             <GridViewColumn Header="SomeStatus" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="170" />
             <GridViewColumn Header="from" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value, StringFormat=0.000000}" Width="170 >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Width="40"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn>
          </GridView>
       </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I forget the specifics but you need the TextBlock to stretch.

Comment: @Blam `<TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>` ?

Comment: You tell me.   Does it work?

Comment: Try HorizontalContentAlignment

Comment: @Blam HorizontalContentAlignment with which Element? There is not HorizontalContentAlignment on GridViewColumn or TextBlock..

Comment: @MikroDel try setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` to **Stretch** against `ListViewItem` in `ItemContainerStyle` then you should be able to right align text in a column

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want just one specific column aligned to the right try the example on

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb961985.aspx

Here's my implementation

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding VolumeNumber}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="SomeStatus" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="170"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="from" Width="170">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" TextAlignment="Right" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

***Now DON'T SET DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" in the GridViewColumn declaration, you need to set it in the textblock*** **Otherwise it will ignore your celltemplate**

*To change the alignment of the column, you need to specify that the HorizontalContentAlignment property of each ListViewItem is Stretch, so that the elements in each ListViewItem can span or be positioned along the entire width of each column. Because the ListView is bound to a data source, you need to create a style that sets the HorizontalContentAlignment. Next, you need to use a DataTemplate to display the content instead of using the DisplayMemberBinding property. To display the Value of each template, the DataTemplate can just contain a TextBlock that has its HorizontalAlignment property set to Right.
The following example defines the style and DataTemplate necessary to make the column right-aligned, and changes the GridViewColumn to reference the DataTemplate.*

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is the `ListViewItem` (i.e. the container of each `GridViewColumn` cell).
You have to set its property `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Have a look here (you also need to remove the `DisplayMemberBinding` if you want to use a DataTemplate):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding VolumeNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn Header="SomeStatus" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="170" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="from" Width="170">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=0.000000}" TextAlignment="Right" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I want to make it possible to accept your answer too :) To give  you more points

Comment: But I will go through your posts and upvote if I find it good for me :)

Comment: No matter @MikroDel. However I appreciate your attempt