# How to Right-align the data in listView (no header) in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have 1 listview with 1 column and no header, how the data is displayed to the right of the column, I have referenced this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123898/wpf-gridviewcolumn-align-doesnt-work), but it is ineffective in my project (sorry my english is not very good). Here is the my xaml code :

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RedTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="RosyBrown"/>
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Mydata}" SelectedItem="{Binding seleItems}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value1}" TextAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20" Content="1" FontSize="25"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20" Content="2" FontSize="25"></Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I hope to receive your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, there's a whole MSDN article on this subject - [How to: Change the Horizontal Alignment of a Column in a ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-change-the-horizontal-alignment-of-a-column-in-a-listview) - and yet they leave out a very important piece of information.

If you take a look at the doc on [GridViewColumn.Width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.width), you'll see two important things:

1. It's a `double`, not a `GridLength` (so no star sizing)
2. This quote:

> The default is NaN, which automatically sizes to the largest column item that is not the column header.

So even though your *items* are stetching to fill the column, your *column* is only as wide as your longest item, not the width of the whole `ListView`.

Now, you could do something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526024/5086631) with code, or you would try binding to `ListView.ActualWidth`, but really, there's a much simpler solution:

**Simple Solution: Just use `ListBox` instead.**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Mydata}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value1}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

A `ListBox` is very similar- if not identical- to a single-column `ListView` with no header. Except the items will actually size the way you want them to.

Comment: thank you @Keith Stein. "So even though your items are stetching to fill the column, your column is only as wide as your longest item, not the width of the whole ListView."  . it awakened me!